# How can I find the expected value of the number of particles in a region?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, astronomy, interstellar-matter

The actual problem asks to find the expected value of number of molecular clouds between Earth and the gallactic center, these clouds are distributed through the gallactic disk approching it as a cylinder of radius R and height H. The molecular clouds are considered to be spheres.
At first I was thinking of something similar to a quatum mechanical approach using $\langle N \rangle = \int_{V}, dr \hat{\rho}(r)$. I already have the total number of molecular clouds in the galaxy aswell as the number density, and distance. But still I don't think it makes much sense taking that approach since we are talking about molecular clouds and not actual particles.

Comment: On a large enough scale, stars in a galaxy look kind of like particles constrained to a volume.